# Why can't I delete from a self inherited dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, delete-operator

I had implemented a dictionary using inherited mechanism like this:

> class NoCaseDict(LoggingHandler, FrozenBase, OrderedDict): ....

Then when I load data from a file, I use this to store data:

```
def makeLowerCaseKey(self, m: Message, using_string=False):
    if using_string:
        mid = m.string.lower()
    else:
        mid = m.id.lower()
    return (mid, m)
```

> dict_data_list = [self.makeLowerCaseKey(m,
> using_string=self.is_using_string) for m in data if len(m.id) > 0]

When I tried to do:

```
del self[key.lower()]
```

I got exception, only printing out the [key.lower()] part. I had to resorted to the method mentioning in this link:
(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary/)

```
new_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in self.items() if (k != lower_key)}
self.clear() 
self.update(new_dict)
```

Though lengthy and worked, I do not know why the command:

```
del self[key.lower()]
```

doesn't work. Do you know why?
I am using Python 3.9.6 on Monterey, macOS.